# c# getting null values of 2 columns from sql table

Tags: c#, sql-server

Basically before i asked a question on how to return the null values from a columns found from a table in sql.  Now i need to know how to do the same thing but for two columns and putting the user name near them which is caught from another column.  This means i have 3 tables.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sql_connection
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[]args)
{

    string conn=null;
    SqlConnection connection;
    conn=("Data Source=Database\\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=Table;User ID=user;Password=example");

     connection=new SqlConnection(conn);
     try{

         connection.Open();
         Console.Writeline("Connection Open!");
         SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT tablein,tableout,tableuser FROM [dbo].[tb_Showingnull]"WHERE tablein AND tableout IS NULL);
         cmd.Connection = connection;
         SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         while(reader.Read())
          {

               Console.WriteLine("{2}, {1} , {0}", reader["tablein"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["tablein"].ToString(); reader["tableout"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["tableout"].ToString(); reader["tableuser"].ToString();

           }

           connection.Close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: You dont need to post the entire code. Just your `SqlCommand`. I think this is what you are looking for `SELECT tablein,tableout,tableuser FROM [dbo].[tb_Showingnull] WHERE tablein IS NULL AND tableout IS NULL`. and always add sample data and expected output so you get quick and accurate answers.

Comment: Why did you put the `"` after `[tb_Showingnull]` and not after the where clause? did you do that by mistake or on purpose?

Comment: Your SqlCommand text is broken: the WHERE part is outside the string quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
SqlCommand cmd= 
new SqlCommand("SELECT tablein,tableout,tableuser FROM 
[dbo].[tb_Showingnull]"WHERE tablein AND tableout IS NULL);
```

Use

```
SqlCommand cmd= 
new SqlCommand("SELECT tablein,tableout,tableuser FROM 
[dbo].[tb_Showingnull] WHERE tablein IS NULL AND tableout IS NULL");
```